# Passing datagrid values to the mysql command parameters

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to add rows from the datagrid to the mysql database. My problem is passing the datagrid values which is

```
dt.Rows[i - 1][1] = dtgPo.Rows[i - 1].Cells["poCode"].Value.ToString();
```

to the

```
cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO poitems (poid,, poCode, itemCode, itemName) VALUES (?id,?pocode,?itemcode,?itemname)", coninsert);
```

Hope that you can help me out guys.Thanks in advance!

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        char pocode;
        char itemcode;
        char itemname;
        int i;

        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM poitems", coninsert);
        MySqlCommandBuilder cb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(da);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);            


        for (i = 1; i < dtgPo.RowCount; i++)
        {
            MySqlDataAdapter da2 = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            MySqlCommand cmd;
            MySqlParameter parm;
            // Create the SelectCommand.

            dt.Rows[i - 1][1] = dtgPo.Rows[i - 1].Cells["poCode"].Value.ToString();
            dt.Rows[i - 1][2] = dtgPo.Rows[i - 1].Cells["itemCode"].Value.ToString();
            dt.Rows[i - 1][3] = dtgPo.Rows[i - 1].Cells["itemName"].Value.ToString();

            cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM poitems", coninsert);

            // Create the InsertCommand.
            cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO poitems (poid,, poCode, itemCode, itemName) VALUES (?id,?pocode,?itemcode,?itemname)", coninsert);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("?id", MySqlDbType.Int16, 11, "poid");
            cmd.Parameters.Add("?pocode", MySqlDbType.Int16, 11, "poCode");
            cmd.Parameters.Add("?itemcode", MySqlDbType.Int16, 11, "itemCode");
            cmd.Parameters.Add("?itemname", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 40, "poCode");

            da2.InsertCommand = cmd;
            //return da;
        }


    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work". What were you expecting, and what actually happen? If you got an exception, post the line it occurred on and the exception details.

Comment: @gunr2171: Thankyou sir, I'm looking for a way to pass dt.Rows[i - 1][1] = dtgPo.Rows[i - 1].Cells["poCode"].Value.ToString(); to cmd.parameters.add. Apparently, passing the datagrid directly to it wouldn't not seem to work. ANy ideas?

Comment: Please edit your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Comment: POst edited sir. I hope that my i made it clear to you guys. My apologies, im new to c# and I'm still in the process of familiarizing everything about it.